# Why are bacteriophage viruses so infrequently used in the western countries?

Tags: bacteria, virus, antibiotics

Bacteriophages are, in eastern countries including Russia, a pretty common, or at least well known, approach to get rid of bacterial infections.
(This is discussed in [How Dangerous Are Superbugs Really? | Virus Vs Bacteria | Spark](https://youtu.be/nIu63eRoRlE)).

Why are phages much less commonly used in the western world?

Intuitively, using a virus that only attacks a specific species of bacteria sounds like a really good form of, or alternative to, antibiotics.

Comment: Can you please supply a link to a reliable source that supports your statement that bacteriophages are used to fight infection? I'd love to read about it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse [How Dangerous Are Superbugs Really? | Virus Vs Bacteria | Spark](https://youtu.be/nIu63eRoRlE) - It's not text, but not as shallow as the fact that it is on youtube may make you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the link. The video is 51 minutes long, though. Do you remember about when they start discussing the bacteriophage as weapon in vivo part? Thanks. :)

Comment: You could check the articles "A historical overview of bacteriophage therapy as an alternative to antibiotics for the treatment of bacterial pathogens" and "Phage therapy: An alternative to antibiotics in the age of multi-drug resistance".